# pygame всплывающее сообщение

Tags: python, pygame

я делаю кнопки, и всплывающие сообщения необходимы, для обьяснения игроку что он натворил. но всплытие происходит только от последней кнопки. я хотел бы чтоб он всплывал с любых кнопок.Я анимацию не могу поставить на всплытие сообщений, чтобы он после нажатия на кнопку - медленно исчезал.
Надеюсь на вашу профессиональность и благородство, и искреннее спасибо тем, кто не поскупился временем помочь столь бедствующему заблудшего

```
import pygame

# === CONSTANTS === (UPPER_CASE names)

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)
HIDE = (0,0,0)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

class Button():
    def __init__(self, text, x = 0, y=0, width = 100, height = 50, command = None):

        self.text = text
        self.command = command

        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_normal.fill(GREEN)

        self.image_hovered = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_hovered.fill(RED)

        self.image_hide = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_hide.fill(HIDE)


        self.image = self.image_normal
        self.image_hided = self.image_hide

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect_hided = self.image_hided.get_rect()
        print(self.rect)

        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 15)

        text_image = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
        text_hide = font.render('i was hided', True, HIDE)
        text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        
        self.image_normal.blit(text_image, text_rect) 
        self.image_hovered.blit(text_image, text_rect)
        self.image_hide.blit(text_hide, text_rect)
        
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)

        self.hovered = False
        self.active = False

    def update(self):
        if self.hovered:
            self.image = self.image_hovered
        else:
            self.image = self.image_normal

        if self.active:
            self.image_hided = self.image_normal


    def draw(self, Surface):
        Surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        Surface.blit(self.image_hided, self.rect_hided)


    def handle_event(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
                
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print(self.text)
            if self.hovered:
                if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    self.active = True
                print('clicked by ',self.text)
                #active = True
                if self.command:
                    command()

                



def main():
    #active = False
    pygame.init()
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    print(screen_rect)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = False

    btn1 = Button('hello', 200, 50, 100, 50)
    btn2 = Button('bye', 200, 150, 100, 50)
    print(btn1)


    run = True

    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False
            
            btn1.handle_event(event)
            btn2.handle_event(event)
            
        
        btn1.update()
        btn2.update()


        screen.fill(BLACK)

        btn1.draw(screen)
        btn2.draw(screen)


        # if active:
        #     bt3 = Button('clicked!!', 200, 200,300,50)
        #     btn3.update()
        #     btn3.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(25)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, то "всплытия" происходят по всех кнопках. У вас они "исчезают" неправильно))) - они просто зачерняются. А последний виден потому, что он самый верхний и он закрывает нижние. В данной ситуации предлагаю сделать отдельный класс всплывающих сообщений, вот он должен будет то отрисовываться то нет в главном цикле. Ну... что-то вроде того)))

Comment: я понял вашу мысль, то есть наследование классов. Будет муторно

Comment: Да. Классы. Главный класс Main. Внутри него кроме классов кнопок будет, к примеру, класс Message, а у него методы set_message,show,hide. set_message - получает в качестве аргумента необходимое сообщение и создаёт текстуру текста, в draw она потом будет отрисовываться.show/hide - показывает/скрывает. Анимация всплывающего сообщения - либо работа с прозрачностью, либо изменение размера, либо перемещение слева направо, либо наоборот. И вот ещё... Текст все же придется переносить на новую строку вручную и... Я не знаю как уместить большой текст в окно сообщения чтобы был с прокруткой.

Comment: Вообще... Обязательно нужно сделать ещё и свой класс событий. К примеру, всплывающее сообщение открыто, а значит все кнопки которые находятся вне этого сообщения становятся не активны, закрыл всплывающее окно - снова активны. Нажал на паузу - игра остановилась, но не висит, а просто не происходит изменений значений во всех игровых объектах, ну и т.д.